# What is the difference between a mongoengine.DynamicEmbeddedDocument vs mongoengine.DictField?

Tags: python, mongoengine

A [mongoengine.DynamicEmbeddedDocument](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.DynamicEmbeddedDocument) can be used to leverage MongoDB's flexible schema-less design. It's expandable and doesn't apply type constraints to the fields, afaik.

A [mongoengine.DictField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.DictField) similarly allows for use of MongoDB's schema-less nature. In the documentation they simply say (w.r.t. the `DictField`)

> This is similar to an embedded document, but the structure is not defined.

Does that mean, then, the `mongoengine.fields.DictField` and the `mongoengine.DynamicEmbeddedDocument` are completely interchangeable?

EDIT (for more information):

`mongoengine.DynamicEmbeddedDocument` inherits from `mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument` which, from the code is:

> A `mongoengine.Document` that isn't stored in its own collection. `mongoengine.EmbeddedDocuments` should be used as fields on `mongoengine.Documents` through the `mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentField` field type.

A `mongoengine.fields.EmbeddedDocumentField` is

> An embedded document field - with a declared document_type. Only valid values are subclasses of `EmbeddedDocument`.

Does this mean the only thing that makes the `DictField` and `DynamicEmbeddedDocument` not totally interchangeable is that the `DynamicEmbeddedDocument` has to be defined through the `EmbeddedDocumentField` field type?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From what I’ve seen, the two are similar, but not entirely interchangeable. Each approach may have a slight advantage based on your needs.  First of all, as you point out, the two approaches require differing definitions in the document, as shown below.

```
class ExampleDynamicEmbeddedDoc(DynamicEmbeddedDocument):
    pass

class ExampleDoc(Document):
    dict_approach = DictField()
    dynamic_doc_approach = EmbeddedDocumentField(ExampleDynamicEmbeddedDoc, default = ExampleDynamicEmbeddedDoc())
```

*Note:* The default is not required, but the dynamic_doc_approach field will need to be set to a ExampleDynamicEmbeddedDoc object in order to save.  (i.e. trying to save after setting example_doc_instance.dynamic_doc_approach = {} would throw an exception).  Also, you could use the GenericEmbeddedDocumentField if you don’t want to tie the field to a specific type of EmbeddedDocument, but the field would still need to be point to an object subclassed from EmbeddedDocument in order to save.

Once set up, the two are functionally similar in that you can save data to them as needed and without restrictions:

```
e = ExampleDoc()
e.dict_approach["test"] = 10
e.dynamic_doc_approach.test = 10
```

However, the one main difference that I’ve seen is that you can query against any values added to a DictField, whereas you cannot with a DynamicEmbeddedDoc.

```
ExampleDoc.objects(dict_approach__test = 10) # Returns a QuerySet containing our entry.
ExampleDoc.objects(dynamic_doc_approach__test = 10) # Throws an exception.
```

That being said, using an EmbeddedDocument has the advantage of validating fields which you know will be present in the document.  (We simply would need to add them to the ExampleDynamicEmbeddedDoc definition).  Because of this, I think it is best to use a DynamicEmbeddedDocument when you have a good idea of a schema for the field and only anticipate adding fields minimally (which you will not need to query against).  However, if you are not concerned about validation or anticipate adding a lot of fields which you’ll query against, go with a DictField.